# Displaying element content as title for tooltip in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a tooltip on several links without coding each "title" atribute. using an id atribute to specify where to get that content from.

This is what I have on the head:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({html : true});
});
</script>
```

Then each link on the HTML body

```
<a href="#eumed"; data-toggle="tooltip" title="#eumed" data-html="true">(Eumed, 2011)</a>
```

And I want the following text to show up on the tooltip text:

```
<p id="eumed">Eumed. (2011). La política comercial estratégica. Recuperado de: <a href="http://www.eumed.net/cursecon/libreria/2004/fs/comestra.htm">http://www.eumed.net/cursecon/libreria/2004/fs/comestra.htm</a></p>
```

I know I can initialize each tooltip with javascript or write each title accordingly BUT the point here is to simplify it.

Here is an [example](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0127900) (hover any number on the article to see the tooltip/popover behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function(){
    var url=$(this).prop('href');
    $(this).tooltip({
      html:true,
      title: $(url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('#'))).html()
    })
  })
});
```

```css
/* Tooltip */
 .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<h3>Tooltip Example</h3>  
<a href="#eumed" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">(Eumed, 2011)</a><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p id="eumed">Eumed. (2011). La polutica comercial estratugica. Recuperado de: <a href="http://www.eumed.net/cursecon/libreria/2004/fs/comestra.htm">comestra</a></p>
</div>
```